# Get Option Description by Option ID (outside the product)

Tags: attributes, magento-1, option

I got Option ID from single attribut in category page by:

```
$request = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

Of course i parse it and i receive attribute name and attribute option ID.

I want description for this single attribute ID.

I receive Title by Attribute Option ID but i don't have any idea how to get description (details) of product. Can someone give me some information about that? My code to get Title:

```
$attributeDetails = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("catalog_product", $main_key);
echo $optionValue = $attributeDetails->getSource()->getOptionText($attribues_id[0]);
```

Thank you!